# How to keep two branches in sync but keep some separate code different?

Tags: git

For example, I have two branches: `master` and `client`

They all have a some file main.c with one line different:

master:main.c:

```
char *private = 'main';
int main() {
/*
...
*/
}
```

client:main.c:

```
char *private = 'client';
int main() {
/*
...
*/
}
```

client branch needs to keep in sync with master but keep the line `char *private` not changed.

How to do this ?

This is a simplified example, in practice, I have a few more different code

Comment: To clarify, you wish to have "aliases" such that if you for example initialize a variable this is created in both branches, with different variable values?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by keeping one of these branches (e.g. master) as base branch and regularly rebase the other branch with it.

```
____master
         |
         |____client
```

when there is a change in `main.c` update it in `master` and then rebase the `client` with the new `master`:

```sh
$ git checkout client
$ git rebase master
```